# Angularjs tiny display bug with ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a small bug with my display logic. User selects job length as step 1 then clicks on a cell to determine availability. Everything works but I need **Selected** to show up on the other cells. I think some sort of boolean I have to attach i'm not sure. Assume for now `jobLength=3` (this comes anyway from the HTML5 custom slider not displayed below but is just above the table as Step 1).How do I get **Selected** to show up.

[image]

Here's the code.

```
  <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="hour in workhours" ng-init="selectedIndex=$index">
                <td>{{hour}}:00 - {{hour+1}}:00</td>

                <td class="hidden-xs" ng-class = "{ 'full'     : !entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour),
                                                    'selected' : renderGreen(selectedIndex, $index, jobLength)}" 
                                      ng-click = "checkSlotAvailability(hour, jobLength, entry, data)"
                                      ng-repeat= "entry in data.calendar">

                        <!-- /* ============ -->
                        <!-- Display Logic   -->
                        <!-- =============== -->
                        <span ng-if="entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour) 
                            && !renderGreen(selectedIndex, $index, jobLength) 
                            && !(selectedIndex == selectedRow 
                            && $index          == selectedColumn)">
                                Available
                        </span>

                        <span ng-if="entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour) 
                            && renderGreen(selectedIndex, $index, jobLength)
                            && $index        == selectedColumn
                            && selectedIndex == selectedRow
                            <!-- I added this check slot f(x) to render table dynamically when user adjusts job length -->
                            && checkSlotAvailability(hour, jobLength, entry, data)">
                                Selected
                        </span>

                        <span ng-if="entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour) 
                            && !renderGreen(selectedIndex, $index, jobLength) 
                            && selectedIndex == selectedRow 
                            && $index        == selectedColumn"> 
                                Unavailable
                        </span>

                        <span ng-if="!entry.HoursAvailable.includes(hour)">
                            Full
                        </span>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

**controller**

```
  (function() {

"use strict";

angular
    .module("availability")
    .controller("availabilityController", function($scope, $http){
        $scope.data          = {};
        $scope.data.response = "Available";
        $scope.workhours     =  Array.from({length:9}).map((_, i)=> i + 9); // creating all possible working hours in a day (9-17)

        $http.get('../api/availability.json')
             .then( function(response){
                $scope.data.calendar = response.data;
        }); 

        function setBuffer(date){
            var today       = formatDateToString(new Date('2016-05-18T11:27:00'));
            var bufferTime  = 1;
            if(date == today){
                bufferTime  = 2;
            }
            return bufferTime;
        }    

        function formatDateToString(date){
            var dd             = (date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getDate();
            var MM             = ((date.getMonth() + 1) < 10 ? '0' : '') + (date.getMonth() + 1);
            var yyyy           = date.getFullYear();
            return (yyyy + "-" + MM + "-" + dd);
        }

        function getRowAndColumn(row, column){
            $scope.selectedRow    = row;
            $scope.selectedColumn = column;
        }

        $scope.renderGreen = function(selectedIndex, $index, jobLength){
            if( $index == $scope.selectedColumn 
                && selectedIndex >= $scope.selectedRow
                && selectedIndex <= ($scope.selectedRow + jobLength - 1) && $scope.data.response == "Available")    
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        /* ===========================
        Check Availabiliy function
        ============================== */
        $scope.checkSlotAvailability = function(time, jobLength, date, availability) {
            var date      = date.Date;
            var calendar  = availability.calendar;
            var response  = "";
            var buffer    = setBuffer(date);
            var selectedIndex = time - 9;



            if( jobLength < 1 || jobLength > 5 ){
                alert("Please enter job length from 1 to 5");
                response = "Available";
            }else {
                for( var i = 0; i < calendar.length; i++ ){

                    getRowAndColumn(selectedIndex, i); 

                    if( date == calendar[i].Date ){

                        if( time < 9 || time > 17 ){    // Can't book before 9am or after 5pm. Code should never reach here.
                            response = "Unavailable";
                            break;
                        }else { 
                            for( var j = 0; j < calendar[i].HoursAvailable.length; j++){

                                if( time == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[j]){
                                    if( ( time == 9 || time == 17 ) && calendar[i].HoursAvailable[j]
                                        || time - buffer < 9
                                        || time == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[j] 
                                        && time - buffer == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[j - buffer] 
                                        && time + buffer == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[j + buffer] ){

                                            for( var k = j; k < calendar[i].HoursAvailable.length; k++ ){

                                                if( time >= 13 && time == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[k] && time + jobLength <= 18 
                                                    && time - buffer   == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[k - buffer] //5pm

                                                    ||  (time + jobLength + (buffer - 1))  == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[k + jobLength + (buffer - 1)] 
                                                    &&  time - buffer                      == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[k - buffer] 

                                                    ||  (time + jobLength + (buffer - 1))  == calendar[i].HoursAvailable[k + jobLength + (buffer - 1)] ){   //9am
                                                        response = "Available";
                                                        break;

                                                }else if( k == calendar[i].HoursAvailable.length - 1 ){
                                                    response = "Unavailable";
                                                }
                                            }
                                            break;
                                    }else{
                                        response = "Unavailable";
                                        break;
                                    }

                                }else if( j == calendar[i].HoursAvailable.length - 1 ){ //no available slot
                                        response = "Full";
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }else if( i == calendar.length - 1 ){   //no available date
                        response = "Full";
                        break;
                    }
                }   
            }
            $scope.data.response = response;
            return response;
        };
    });

})();
```

Comment: Why are u checking slot availability in ng-if of selected? And I don't see you invoking any function on click of cell row that will capture $index and selectedIndex?

Comment: there's `ng-click` on the `<td>` where the `ng-repeat` is. I get what you're trying to understand. Without the slot checking function on Select span, yes it works fine (it's what I was doing before).. all the green cells show Selected as desired but my table stops being dynamic. I require the table to render dynamically when user adjusts the slider the second time. Basically The table must be rendered dynamically from the data, and updated when the job length changes.

Comment: Ok, but if it was two way binding then the change in slider should reflect on table irrespective of the checkSlotAvailability functionality. Anyways what exactly is checkSlotAvailability returning? And also selectedIndex >= $scope.selectedRow means that it is checking row wise but u want column wise, so won't selectedIndex <= ($scope.selectedRow + jobLength - 1) suffice for columns?

Comment: At that particular cell (Thursday 19th - 9am) shown above, it returns "Available" as required.

Comment: Maybe try calling checkSlotAvailability(hour, jobLength, entry, data)">
                                Selected before renderGreen(selectedIndex, $index, jobLength) in your ng-gi for selected?

Comment: Does not work. That now checks all the cells in the table for possible availability thus rendering all available cells in the table green (without even clicking) with the words "Available" and "Selected" both in the cell. But seems like a good queue to follow up. I actually was not aware the order of `&&` statements matters speaking generally of programming.

Comment: You can check if checkSlotAvailability is returning none of the above fields that is Available, Full or Unavailable by checkSlotAvailability(hour, jobLength, entry, data)!='Available' && checkSlotAvailability(hour, jobLength, entry, data)!='Full' && checkSlotAvailability(hour, jobLength, entry, data)!='Unavailable'  then show selected?